# matplotlib style use has no effect

Tags: python, matplotlib

python 3.8.10, matplotlib 3.5.1

There is no difference in the resulting plot whether I use `plt.style.use()` with different arguments or not at all with this script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

x_fair = [20, 35, 85]
wer_fair = [49, 42, 31]

x_mine = [18.4, 39.4]
wer_mine = [32, 30]

def main():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.scatter(x_fair, wer_fair, c='r')
    ax.plot(x_fair, wer_fair, c='r', label='fairseq')

    ax.scatter(x_mine, wer_mine, c='b')
    ax.plot(x_mine, wer_mine, c='b', label='Mine')

    ax.set_xlabel('steps in k')
    ax.set_ylabel('WER')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()


main()
```

It's like the library has disabled the use of `style.use()` ??

Comment: I don't reproduce your issue. Maybe you already had 'ggplot'? Try setting `plt.style.use('default')` or another style

Comment: I can set it to any other style and there is no difference in output